# Get list of methods in class using clang

Tags: c++, parsing, clang, code-inspection, outliner

In common IDEs (pick one) you often have an outline view showing you the list of methods for a specific class.

Suppose I have a C++ interface class in `IFoo.h` that looks like this:

```cpp
#ifndef IFOO_H_
#define IFOO_H_
class IFoo { 
    public:
        virtual ~IFoo() {}
        virtual void bar() = 0;
};
#endif
```

How (programmatically) can I get such an IDE outliner list for my `IFoo.h` file above using maybe the clang libraries? For a first start, it would help if I can get a list of names of functions.

I specifically intend to use clang, so any help on how to analyze the my header file with clang would be really appreciated.

Meanwhile I will have a look at the clang tutorial here: https://github.com/loarabia/Clang-tutorial

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I went through this tutorial http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersTutorial.html and found some pretty helpful stuff there, this is what I came up with:

<strike>I had to rename my file from `IFoo.h` to `IFoo.hpp` to be detected as Cxx and not C code.</strike>

I had to call my program with `-x c++` to have my `IFoo.h` file being recognized as C++ code rather than C code (clang interprets `*.h` files as C by default:

```
~/Development/llvm-build/bin/mytool ~/IFoo.h -- -x c++
```

This is my code to dump all virtual functions from the provided class:

```cpp
// Declares clang::SyntaxOnlyAction.
#include "clang/Frontend/FrontendActions.h"
#include "clang/Tooling/CommonOptionsParser.h"
#include "clang/Tooling/Tooling.h"
#include "clang/ASTMatchers/ASTMatchers.h"
// Declares llvm::cl::extrahelp.
#include "llvm/Support/CommandLine.h"

#include "clang/ASTMatchers/ASTMatchers.h"
#include "clang/ASTMatchers/ASTMatchFinder.h"

#include <cstdio>

using namespace clang;
using namespace clang::ast_matchers;
using namespace clang::tooling;
using namespace llvm;

DeclarationMatcher methodMatcher = methodDecl(isVirtual()).bind("methods");

class MethodPrinter : public MatchFinder::MatchCallback {
public :
  virtual void run(const MatchFinder::MatchResult &Result) {
    if (const CXXMethodDecl *md = Result.Nodes.getNodeAs<clang::CXXMethodDecl>("methods")) {    
      md->dump();
    }
  }
};

// CommonOptionsParser declares HelpMessage with a description of the common
// command-line options related to the compilation database and input files.
// It's nice to have this help message in all tools.
static cl::extrahelp CommonHelp(CommonOptionsParser::HelpMessage);

// A help message for this specific tool can be added afterwards.
static cl::extrahelp MoreHelp("\nMore help text...");

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {    
  cl::OptionCategory cat("myname", "mydescription");
  CommonOptionsParser optionsParser(argc, argv, cat, 0);    

  ClangTool tool(optionsParser.getCompilations(), optionsParser.getSourcePathList());

  MethodPrinter printer;
  MatchFinder finder;
  finder.addMatcher(methodMatcher, &printer);
  return tool.run(newFrontendActionFactory(&finder));
}
```

The output looks like this, when passed the `IFoo.h` file:

```cpp
CXXDestructorDecl 0x1709c30 <~/IFoo.h:5:3, col:20> ~IFoo 'void (void)' virtual
`-CompoundStmt 0x1758128 <col:19, col:20>
CXXMethodDecl 0x1757e60 <~/IFoo.h:6:3, col:24> bar 'void (void)' virtual pure
```

Comment: Did you investigate how to inspect methods of a particular access level? I'm not sure exactly how to only inspect public methods. Specifically, I need the location of the last public method.

Comment: I will show you how to do it when Im back at my computer later today or tomorrow morning. I only have a cellphone at hand right now.

Comment: I posted this as a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564494/clang-retrieving-public-methods if you'd like to answer. Thanks!