# Detecting functions using C/C++

Tags: c++, c, function, parsing

I have a project with lots of files which I want to add a simple "printf" command to each function found in each file. Please share your ideas on how to detect a function programmatically.

Comment: By programmatically, you mean a program that will scan the code file as a text file?

Comment: Generally, you should show some efforts from your side for others to help you out.

Comment: What you want to deduct? is it a function name

Comment: @SharonJDDorot Yes a program that reads a .c file, detects all function in that and adds a "printf" to each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I hate to be *that guy* and immediately tell you that you're doing it wrong, and I have no idea what you actually want to accomplish with this (care to further explain?), you are going to get a lot more insight into your code using a debugger or profiler.  If you want see all the function calls leading up to some event in your program (like a crash), try gdb.  If you want stats on how often functions are being called, look into something like Valgrind or gprof.  The following question goes on at length about profiling C++:

[What can I use to profile C++ code in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux)

But, if you're really determined to get a printf into every single function, I would use a third party tool that does C++ parsing.  Trying to write regexes to parse C++ yourself is going to be an exercise in frustration.

CScope is probably the easiest "off the shelf" solution: http://cscope.sourceforge.net/ 
Note that it might have trouble with C++ code that is heavy on template programming.

If you want to invest some more serious time into this, developing a solution with the open-source clang compiler would allow you to make something really comprehensive.  Check out http://clang.llvm.org/

example of something in the ballpark of what you're doing: [Get list of methods in class using clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878260/get-list-of-methods-in-class-using-clang)

Hope that helps...

Comment: Besides templates, lambda's are also going to be fun for CScope.

Answer (score 1):

use `__FUNCTION__` and `__LINE__` macro. Hope this will be helpfull

```
#define PRINT_FUNC_NAME() do{printf("Entered the function %s in line no %d",__FUNCTION__,__LINE__)}while(0)
```

Sample program

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#define PRINT_FUNC_NAME() do {printf("Entered the function %s in line no %d\n",__FUNCTION__,__LINE__) } while(0)


void callme()
{
   PRINT_FUNC_NAME();
}
int main()
{
   PRINT_FUNC_NAME();
      callme();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Never hide a `;` inside a macro. Have a `;` after each invocation, instead. This helps a lot making the code readable. Also for such a macro that clearly performs a function, it is much easier to read when defined as functional macro and called as `PRINT_FUNC_NAME()`.

Comment: do{ printf("blahblah")l } while(0) is often a recommended method to use Macros.

Comment: @JensGustedt Edited as per your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: @Stolas I was not clear about your statment. Kindly clarify

Comment: Well like Jens said don't hide a ; inside a macro.
Something that I do often (and seen other people do a lot is:
#define PRINT_FUNC_NAME() do{ printf("Entered the function %s in line no %d\n",__FUNCTION__,__LINE__); }while(0) 
As it has kinda best of both worlds and if you have a Typo in your Macro it won't spill over the rest of the code while debugging ;) (note I am not saying you must, I am saying you should/could)

Comment: @Stolas Really I cannot understand why we have to use do{ printf("Entered the function %s in line no %d\n",FUNCTION,LINE); }while(0)  . What makes this special from usual. Can you please some samples

Comment: @vinothcse2000 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macros I think this will explain it :)

Comment: @Stolas Really helped me out. Note my edits