# Clang: Retrieving public methods

Tags: c++, clang, llvm-clang

I want to define a function that will return a pointer to the last defined public method using the Clang LibTooling library.

Currently I have a `CXXRecordDecl` pointer `*decl` and the following line to get the source location of the first method.

```
const SourceLocation method_begin_location = decl->method_begin()->getLocation();
```

Ideally, I want to replace this with a function to get the location of the last defined public method or the location of the beginning of the public declaration if there are no methods as follows.

```
const SourceLocation last_public_method_location = get_last_public_method_loc(decl);
```

Any insights into writing this function? `method_end()` points past the end of the method definitions so it is not as helpful as I was hoping.

Comment: This level of compile-time reflection is not upported (yet). There is even less runtime type infortmation.

Answer (score 3):

This might be something you could try. I have one variable, that shall store the name of the last public method that you *explicitly* defined, meaning that it wasn't added by the compiler automatically. Each function that matches the `methodDecl(isPublic(), unless(isImplicit()))` matcher will be stored in the `lastPublicMethodName` string variable which in the end will contain the last visited method.

I can highly recommend keeping this site in your back pocket for all the AST matchers: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html. Also, `tools/clang/unitests/ASTMatchers/ASTMatchersTest.cpp` is a valuable resource if you want to find out how a particular matcher works.

This is the code I parse:

**/tmp/Foo.hpp:**

```
class Foo { 
    public:
        virtual ~Foo() {}
        virtual void somePublicFunction1() = 0;
        virtual void somePublicFunction2() = 0;
        virtual void somePublicFunction3() = 0;
        virtual void somePublicFunction4() = 0;
        virtual void somePublicFunction5() = 0;
    private:
        virtual void somePrivateFunction1() = 0;
        virtual void somePrivateFunction2() = 0;
        virtual void somePrivateFunction3() = 0;
        virtual void somePrivateFunction4() = 0;
        virtual void somePrivateFunction5() = 0;
};
```

Here's the program code of my Clang tool:

**llvm/tools/clang/tools/extra/mytool/MyTool.cpp**

```
// Declares clang::SyntaxOnlyAction.
#include "clang/Frontend/FrontendActions.h"
#include "clang/Tooling/CommonOptionsParser.h"
#include "clang/Tooling/Tooling.h"
// Declares llvm::cl::extrahelp.
#include "llvm/Support/CommandLine.h"
#include "clang/ASTMatchers/ASTMatchers.h"
#include "clang/ASTMatchers/ASTMatchFinder.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace clang;
using namespace clang::ast_matchers;
using namespace clang::tooling;
using namespace llvm;

// Apply a custom category to all command-line options so that they are the
// only ones displayed.
static llvm::cl::OptionCategory MyToolCategory("my-tool options");

// CommonOptionsParser declares HelpMessage with a description of the common
// command-line options related to the compilation database and input files.
// It's nice to have this help message in all tools.
static cl::extrahelp CommonHelp(CommonOptionsParser::HelpMessage);

// A help message for this specific tool can be added afterwards.
static cl::extrahelp MoreHelp("\nMore help text...");

DeclarationMatcher methodMatcher = methodDecl(isPublic(),unless(isImplicit())).bind("methods");

class MethodPrinter : public MatchFinder::MatchCallback {
public :
  virtual void run(const MatchFinder::MatchResult &Result) {
    if (const CXXMethodDecl *md = Result.Nodes.getNodeAs<clang::CXXMethodDecl>("methods")) {    
      lastPublicMethodName = md->getNameAsString();
    }
  }

  std::string lastPublicMethodName;
};

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
  CommonOptionsParser OptionsParser(argc, argv, MyToolCategory);
  ClangTool Tool(OptionsParser.getCompilations(),
                 OptionsParser.getSourcePathList());

  MethodPrinter Printer;
  MatchFinder Finder;
  Finder.addMatcher(methodMatcher, &Printer);

  Tool.run(newFrontendActionFactory(&Finder).get());

  std::cout << "The last public method is: " << Printer.lastPublicMethodName << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I hope, this helps you.

Comment: I guess although this "technically" works. I have other functionality in my matcher where I can't wait until the whole matching process is completed before having a pointer to the last public method. Thanks for the example, I think I may end up writing a matcher for just the public method body. I was hoping someone could help me with using the method_iterator, I'm new to C++.